# How do I deal with infinite P-values? Should I remove it?

Tags: r, data-science, bioinformatics, infinite, infinity

I ordered a list of genes by P-value in the form of a `top.genes.matrix` expression matrix. The `dat.filtered` dataframe is in log2 scale, which is filtered from the original `dat` dataframe. 
Most of my top genes have infinite values. Is there an error in my code? How should I treat the infinite values? Remove it?

```
# Convert dat to numeric matrix
samp.matrix <- data.matrix(dat[, (3:ncol(dat))])

# Correlation Matrix
dat.cor  <- cor(samp.matrix, method="pearson", use="pairwise.complete.obs")

# Average correlation plot
dat.avg <- apply(dat.cor, 1, mean, na.rm=T)
# Remove Outlier(s) 
samp.matrix <- samp.matrix[, -(grep(names(outlier), colnames(samp.matrix)))]

# Eliminate probes with rowMeans less than 0 on a log2 scale
dat.fil <- subset(samp.matrix, log2(rowMeans(samp.matrix)) > 0)
removed <- nrow(samp.matrix) - nrow(dat.fil)

# Eliminate probes with rowMeans less than 3 on a log2 scale
dat.filtered <- subset(dat.fil, rowMeans(dat.fil) > 3)
dat.filtered <- as.data.frame(dat.filtered)
removed  <- nrow(dat.fil) - nrow(dat.filtered)

# Student's t-test function 
rawp <- c()
t.test.all.genes <- function(x,s1,s2) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  x1 <- x[s1]
  x2 <- x[s2]
  x1 <- as.numeric(x1)
  x2 <- as.numeric(x2)
  t.out <- t.test(x1,x2, alternative="two.sided",var.equal=T)
  out <- as.numeric(t.out$p.value)
  return(out)
}
# Raw p-value for ontrol and glioma samples
rawp <- apply(dat.filtered, 1, t.test.all.genes, s1=is.ctl, s2=is.glioma)

# Ordering the highest genes (by P-value) in the form of a data.frame
# Note: dat.filtered is still in log2 scale
best.genes    <- order(rawp)[1:length(rawp)]
best.genes.df <- data.frame(index=best.genes, exp=2^dat.filtered[best.genes, ], rawp=rawp[best.genes])
# Expression matrix with the 'best.genes' in the original scale (based on P-value ranking)
top.genes.matrix <- 2^dat.filtered[best.genes, ]

> dput(dat[1:5, 1:5])
structure(list(ID_REF = c("1007_s_at", "1053_at", "117_at", "121_at", 
"1255_g_at"), IDENTIFIER = c("MIR4640", "RFC2", "HSPA6", "PAX8", 
"GUCA1A"), NB_GSM97800 = c(4701.5, 282.7, 769.6, 1616.3, 232.7
), NB_GSM97803 = c(4735, 347.9, 287.9, 1527.2, 204.8), NB_GSM97804 = c(2863.9, 
355, 199, 1793.8, 119.3)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

   
> dput(dat.filtered[1:5, 1:5])
structure(list(NB_GSM97800 = c(4701.5, 282.7, 769.6, 1616.3, 
232.7), NB_GSM97803 = c(4735, 347.9, 287.9, 1527.2, 204.8), NB_GSM97804 = c(2863.9, 
355, 199, 1793.8, 119.3), NB_GSM97805 = c(5350.2, 319.9, 182.8, 
1880, 180.2), NB_GSM97807 = c(4789.4, 294.2, 204.3, 1012, 156.7
)), row.names = c("1007_s_at", "1053_at", "117_at", "121_at", 
"1255_g_at"), class = "data.frame")


> > head(rawp)    1007_s_at      1053_at       117_at       121_at    1255_g_at      1294_at 
> 6.631006e-14 1.111397e-05 5.772347e-02 9.229543e-02 7.378613e-24 1.027390e-05
> 
> dput(best.genes.df[1:5, 1:5])
structure(list(index = c(29035L, 49756L, 23236L, 49011L, 15902L
), exp.NB_GSM97800 = c(960, 819.6, 3156.3, 1809.7, 2540.5), exp.NB_GSM97803 = c(1509.1, 
732.7, 4206.9, 1851.2, 3455.3), exp.NB_GSM97804 = c(1121.2, 138.3, 
3442.1, 645.4, 1764.5), exp.NB_GSM97805 = c(1365.6, 431.6, 2783.3, 
1261.8, 1990.1)), row.names = c("219752_at", "240512_x_at", "213938_at", 
"239767_at", "206456_at"), class = "data.frame")
> 
> dput(top.genes.matrix[1:5, 1:5])
structure(list(NB_GSM97800 = c(9.7453140114e+288, 5.29888441356601e+246, 
Inf, Inf, Inf), NB_GSM97803 = c(Inf, 3.67009936848685e+220, Inf, 
Inf, Inf), NB_GSM97804 = c(Inf, 4.2899121663437e+41, Inf, 1.92645647596287e+194, 
Inf), NB_GSM97805 = c(Inf, 8.40516277768061e+129, Inf, Inf, Inf
), NB_GSM97807 = c(Inf, 5.18689446110124e+179, Inf, Inf, Inf)), row.names = c("219752_at", 
"240512_x_at", "213938_at", "239767_at", "206456_at"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You're definitely doing something wrong. P-values can only be between 0 and 1.

Comment: You also refer to dat.filtered but never define it in your question. Please consider a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Dason thank you for the suggestion. I amended the question. `dat.filtered` is a dataframe that is derived from `dat` by filtering out the outliers.

Comment: This is going in the right direction but is still not a [mcve] (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ).  Searching your code, I can't see where `rawp` is defined (and even if so, it wouldn't be reproducible/we would be guessing because we don't have `dat` ...)

Comment: @BenBolker, I've now added `dput(dat[1:5,1:5])` and defined `rawp` as per your suggestion.

Comment: Are any of the estimated coefficients Inf or 0 (i.e. the covariate has no variation when stratified by the dependent variable)?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a shot in the dark given your presented data is slightly murky, but a quick survey shows that:

```
2^(c(1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4, 1e5))
[1]  1.024000e+03  1.267651e+30 1.071509e+301           Inf           Inf
```

So if `any(dat.filtered[best.genes, ] > 1e4)` that will clue you in to where R is converting values that are 'too large' for it to think about to `Inf`.

Comment: This is probably what's causing the issue. But honestly OP shouldn't be doing 2^anything to get their p-values. So they really need to figure that out first because honestly the Inf issue might be a good thing for them because they're definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: Does it make sense if I do this:
`best.genes    <- order(rawp)[1:length(rawp)]
best.genes.df <- data.frame(index=best.genes, rawp=rawp[best.genes])
top.genes.matrix <- dat.filtered[best.genes, ]`

Comment: It's difficult for us to make sense of what you're doing in total, so the conservative answer is "no, it probably doesn't make sense". As others have pointed out, you have a lot of moving pieces in your code that aren't clearly described, and your code still isn't reproducible. You seem to be giving us different subsets of objects that represent different transformations of some source data. And as others have pointed taking `2^` of a vector, in the context of your question, and the object names, doesn't make a whole lot of sense either.